# slackpkg is slow, can I kill it?

Tags: slackware

I'm doing a

```
slackpkg update
slackpkg upgrade-all
```

and the copying from the mirror sites are taking too long; if I kill the process, will it start all over again?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Why do you think killing and restarting it will make things any faster?

Comment: @EEAA, Just a thought.

Comment: Killing the process, change download mirror (one nearest your location) and then update and upgrade-all could speed up the things.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed designed to be able to recover from it.

That said, it is always better to be cautious with such processes which could leave the system in an unstable state should any problem occur because of your `kill`.

Comment: It's about half way done, if I go home now it will be finished but I won't be able to hit 'ENTER' on the keyboard to finish the update. What should I do?

Comment: Next time, run your updates inside of a GNU Screen session...